# Is it possible to add new app into my Salesforce mobile?

Tags: mobile, app, app-launcher

In my App Launcher I have only these apps available.
Is it possible to add custom one with my defined tabs?

[image: App Launcher]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To add the app to App Launcher follow the below steps:

1. Go to Setup in Lightning -> App Manager
2. Create New Lightning App
3. On App Options tab for "Supported From Factors" select "Desktop and phone" or "Phone" option
   [image]

It is also possible to Edit existing Lightning App and set the above option correctly.